# How to stop search engines (duck duck go/google in particular) to cut titles of web pages

Tags: search-engine, google-search, duckduckgo

Some titles of search results get cut of with three dots (...). This is very annoying, especialy when you search for coding errors, because the relevant information is at the end of the title. See example:

[image: Cut page title]

Is there a possibility to make Duck Duck Go or Google show the entire title of a page?
Is there an alternative search engine, which shows the entire page title?

Answer (score -1):

Just try to keep your titles between 50-70 chars.

If you will make them longer, Google can crop even to 40-50 chars.

Comment: I actually search for something. I do not want to optimize my title on my site